# javascript variable comparison behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I am facing very strange issue while I am trying to compare two string with the help of regex. also I tried to compare both variable in watch, but unfortunately I am getting same result. Please help me to find the cause.
My code is below and I am attaching an image where I have compared two variable values.
In below code, for ex: if `text="Acworth, GA"` and `search="Acworth, GA"` or `search="acworth, ga"` then `final_str` does not have `<span class="highlight"`.

I'll really appreciate if you have any suggestion.

```
app.filter('highlight', function($filter, $sce) {
  return function(text, search, caseSensitive) {
    if (search == undefined)
      search = searchDataBrowser;

    text = text.toString();
    search = search.toString();

    var reg = new RegExp(search, 'gi');

    var final_str = text.replace(reg, function(str) {
      return '<span class="highlight">' + str + '</span>'
    });

    return $sce.trustAsHtml(final_str);
  };
});
```

[image]

Comment: Try `typeof search === 'undefined'`

Comment: The code seems to work for the shown input and the given code: The [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3t4zjxvo/) shows `<span class="highlight">Acworth, GA</span>` as result, so what is wrong about that?

Comment: @ChrisLam- It works when you manually assign values to variable but when it get input from filter and it does not return expected output even  value is same as I mentioned above.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of my problem. Thanks guys for your valuable time.
Problem was in first string value, while rendering the input it contains   for space. That is why you can check on attached image , the same values do not match each other.
I simply remove the &nbsp from binding, and it works for me.